# VHDL FSM not compiling

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I've created the following fsm to control a fir filter but I'm getting two errors while compiling.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity fsm is
generic (n: integer:=4);
port( clk: in STD_LOGIC;
        rst: in STD_LOGIC;
        a: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*n-1 downto 0));
end fsm;

architecture fsm_struct of fsm is
type state_type is (state0, state1, state2);
signal state: state_type;   

signal rstff, rom_enable, ram_read_enable, ram_write_enable: STD_LOGIC;




component filter_rom is
    generic (n: integer);
    port ( clk: in STD_LOGIC;
            rstff: in STD_LOGIC;
            rom_enable : in STD_LOGIC;
            ram_read_enable : in STD_LOGIC;
            ram_write_enable : in STD_LOGIC;
            a: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*n-1 downto 0));           
end component;


begin   



process(clk,rst)    
    variable delay1:integer:=0;
    variable delay2:integer:=0;
    variable delay3:integer:=0;
begin   
    if rst='1' then
        state<=state0;          
    else if rising_edge(clk) then

        case state is

            when state0 => --initialize & input data
                rom_enable<='1';
                rstff<='1'; 
                if delay1=1 then
                    rstff<='0';
                    state<=state1;
                    delay2:=0;
                else
                    delay1:=delay1+1;
                    state<=state0;
                end if;

            when state1 => --write data to ram
                if delay2=2 then
                    ram_write_enable<='1';
                    state<=state2;
                    delay3:=0;
                else
                    delay2:=delay2+1;
                    state<=state1;
                end if;


            when state2 => --read data from ram
                if delay3=1 then
                    ram_read_enable<='1';
                    state<=state0;
                    delay1:=0;
                else
                    delay3:=delay3+1;
                    state<=state2;
                end if;

        end case;
    end if;

end process;

filter0: filter_memory generic map(n=>n) port map(clk,rstff,rom_enable,ram_read_enable,ram_write_enable,a);

end fsm_struct;
```

The errors I'm getting are: Line 83: Syntax error near "process",
Line 85: Syntax error near "generic". at the end of the program. I know that my code won't even compile to any of your machines as my filter is not defined, but I need some help from a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: I didn't know you can declare variables in an architecture. Are you sure they are not the cause of the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I moved them inside the process and nothing changed.

EDIT: stupid me wrote 'elsif' as 'else if'.

Comment: @Bill indeed: so you ca probably answer your own question. Or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I used 'else if' instead of 'elsif' and it didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`filter0: filter_memory generic map(n=>n)` but your component name is `filter_rom`

try

`filter0: filter_rom generic map(n=>n)`

If you changed else if to elsif change it here also.

It compiles in Vivado 2017.4